# Bivariate random variables that are different even though the corresponding univariate r.v. are the same

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am asked to provide two random variables, $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y = (Y_1, Y_2),$ taking values in $\mathbb{N_{0}}^2,$ such that $X_1, Y_1$ and $X_2, Y_2$, respectively, have the same distribution but $X$ and $Y$ don't.

Let's suppose $X_1, Y_1$ have the Poisson distribution and let's say $X_2, Y_2$ the uniform one. It is unclear to my, why $X, Y$ would not necessarily have the same distribution. Can somebody provide an example of a bivariate random variable satisfying the required property ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the marginal distributions are the same? If so, set $X_1=X_2=Y_1$ and take $Y_2$ to be an independent copy of $Y_1$.

Answer (score 4):

All four variables have the same distribution.  $X_1$ independent of $X_2$ while $Y_1=Y_2$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate little bit why $X$ and $Y$ in that scenario will not have the same distribution ? In fact the situation that you provide is very intriguing. Since by hypothesis $X_1 = Y_1$ and $X_2 = Y_2,$ following your example we will get $X_1 = Y_1 = Y_2$ and thus $X_1 = Y_1 = Y_2 = X_2,$ while $X_1$ being independent to $X_2.$ I cant see further.

Comment: @user996159 note that $X$ will be concentrated in the diagonal while $Y$ will be spread all over the matrix (I am assuming that both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete and their probabilities are written in matricial form $m_{i,j}$ is the probability of $X = (i,j)$ or of $Y = (i,j)$),

Comment: I answered the question posed in the first paragraph.  My assumption is that they all have the same distribution, not they are all equal.  Example:  all variables are coin flips.  For $X$, there are two independent coin flips, while for $Y$ there is one coin flip applying to both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To make this more concrete. $X_{1}$ is the red die; $X_{2}$ is the blue
die; $Y_{1}$ is the green die and $Y_{2}$ is the same throw of the green die
as $Y_{1}$.